# Is it possible to retrieve the GPRMC from device GPS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, location

I 'm looking for a way to obtain the GPRMC info from device GPS.

Is it even possible in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.
First GPRMC is a message from the text based NMEA protocoll, which is a not well defined protocoll, each chip manufacturer interprets it differently.
Therfore most professional devices, use the binary protocoll from the Chip manufacturer.
And even when Apple woud internally use the NMEA Protokoll to communicate with the chip, you would not have any access to that messages.

However the data of the GPRMC message is available in CLLocation delivered by CLLocationManager.

Lets look at the attributes of RMC:

- time: no not really, apple may correct the time by local time, or by a user correction offset
  offset.
- validFlag: yes in CLLocation
- latitude: yes
- longitude: yes
- speed: yes
- course: yes (CLLocation.course)
- Magnetic Variation: yes possible, but needs an API call.

Comment: Apple doesn't provide bearing/azimuth and I'm using calculation but it's far more better if they'd a built in function for it or using the GPRMC.

Comment: @IdanMoshe Apple of course provide bearing: It is called CLLocation.course

Comment: @IdanMoshe because you are using the simulator. go out into real life.

Comment: make sure your device has a GPS chip! the cheap ipads (wlan only) dont have gps. iPhone4 and 4s and for sure the 5 er have course. and course is only available if you move. (and read the Location awareness guide)

Comment: the course attribute is only available if you use BEST location quality. cell tower locations will not have a course info attached. (it stays -1=

Answer (score 2):

There's no public API to retrieve the GPRMC from the device's GPS chip.
The closest you can get to that is to build the GPRMC sentences from what the Location API provides you.

The following code builds the GPRMC and GPGGA sentences from CLLocation, in Swift. It's based on [this question](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9838/olympus-air%E3%81%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9E%E3%83%9B%E3%81%AE%E7%8F%BE%E5%9C%A8%E5%9C%B0%E3%82%92%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95) and on the [NMEA specification](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm) for those sentences. Some data is hard-coded because we don't have access to that on iOS.

On your `CLLocationManagerDelegate`:

```
let timestampFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
let nmeaDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

init () {
    timestampFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
    timestampFormatter.dateFormat = "HHmmss.SSS"

    nmeaDateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
    nmeaDateFormatter.dateFormat = "ddMMyy"
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    for location in locations {
        let latitude = convertCLLocationDegreesToNmea(location.coordinate.latitude)
        let longitude = convertCLLocationDegreesToNmea(location.coordinate.longitude)

        // GPGGA
        // http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#GGA
        var nmea0183GPGGA = "GPGGA," + timestampFormatter.stringFromDate(location.timestamp)
        nmea0183GPGGA += String(format: ",%08.4f,", arguments: [abs(latitude)])
        nmea0183GPGGA += latitude > 0.0 ? "N" : "S"
        nmea0183GPGGA += String(format: ",%08.4f,", arguments: [abs(longitude)])
        nmea0183GPGGA += longitude > 0.0 ? "E" : "W"
        nmea0183GPGGA += ",1,08,1.0,"
        nmea0183GPGGA += String(format: "%1.1f,M,%1.1f,M,,,", arguments: [location.altitude, location.altitude])
        nmea0183GPGGA += String(format: "*%02lX", arguments: [nmeaSentenceChecksum(nmea0183GPGGA)])
        nmea0183GPGGA = "$" + nmea0183GPGGA

        // GPRMC
        // http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#RMC
        var nmea0183GPRMC = "GPRMC," + timestampFormatter.stringFromDate(location.timestamp) + ",A,"
        nmea0183GPRMC += String(format: "%08.4f,", arguments: [abs(latitude)])
        nmea0183GPRMC += latitude > 0.0 ? "N" : "S"
        nmea0183GPRMC += String(format: ",%08.4f,", arguments: [abs(longitude)])
        nmea0183GPRMC += longitude > 0.0 ? "E" : "W"
        nmea0183GPRMC += String(format: ",%04.1f,", arguments: [(location.course > 0.0 ? location.speed * 3600.0 / 1000.0 * 0.54 : 0.0)])
        nmea0183GPRMC += String(format: "%04.1f,", arguments: [(location.course > 0.0 ? location.course : 0.0)])
        nmea0183GPRMC += nmeaDateFormatter.stringFromDate(location.timestamp)
        nmea0183GPRMC += ",,,A"
        nmea0183GPRMC += String(format: "*%02lX", arguments: [nmeaSentenceChecksum(nmea0183GPRMC)])
        nmea0183GPRMC = "$" + nmea0183GPRMC

        // Log
        debugPrint(nmea0183GPGGA)
        debugPrint(nmea0183GPRMC)
    }
}

func convertCLLocationDegreesToNmea(degrees: CLLocationDegrees) -> Double {
    let degreeSign = ((degrees > 0.0) ? 1.0 : ((degrees < 0.0) ? -1.0 : 0));
    let degree = abs(degrees);
    let degreeDecimal = floor(degree);
    let degreeFraction = degree - degreeDecimal;
    let minutes = degreeFraction * 60.0;
    let nmea = degreeSign * (degreeDecimal * 100.0 + minutes);
    return nmea;
}

func nmeaSentenceChecksum(sentence: String) -> CLong {
    var checksum: unichar = 0;
    var stringUInt16 = [UInt16]()
    stringUInt16 += sentence.utf16
    for char in stringUInt16 {
        checksum ^= char
    }
    checksum &= 0x0ff
    return CLong(checksum)
}
```

Comment: The question is whether the OP wants a RMC formated message or if he wants the content of such a RMC message.

Comment: Updated the explanation to address that

Comment: Thanks @brnunes for the efforts. Could you write the methods to get `GPGSA` and `GNGSA` as I need `VDOP`, `POD` & Satellites count.