# Get real time (not local time) on offline mobile devices

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, time, gps

I'm looking for a way to get the current time (Hours Minutes Seconds) for a user's iPhone. Im trying not to get the local time (that is editable by the user) but I‘d like to get the exact time for this user (not the device time) within the right time zone.

One way to achieve this is maybe to make something like a Server-request (JSON request) sending the GPS position.

But is there also a way to achieve this with no actice internet comnection? Maybe using GPS?

Comment: have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227413/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-gprmc-from-device-gps

Comment: @DixitAkabari I’m pretty sure this is not the right answer to my question. I‘ve asked for a way to get the real time (not device time) in offline Mode. LatLongToTimezone libary is just translating coordinates to timezones- timezones are no TIME just zones

Comment: The short answer is no. An user can always change the device's local time. Your best case is to make a server-request to get the server time. As you have already figured out you can detect time zone difference. What is more, you would be better not asking for time value, but for time interval to event you are scheduling(for instance after 5 minutes - will be 5x60 = 300). This way you can take the current device time and add the returned value by the server. Note this will not resolve the issue where the user returns his/her local time. Not an answer to your question, just some random thoughts.

Comment: As a short overview of my previous comment, you are highly dependable on server time for time related operations :)