# How to get NMEA frames with LocationManager in Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I've created a LocationListener and I do get the location updates, but I would like to get NMEA frames, as with GpsStatus.NmeaListener or OnNmeaMessageListener on Android, not just the Location object. Is there something similar in CodenameOne?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [native interface](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) to do that but that won't work on iOS. As far as I can tell [iOS doesn't support that level of fine events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227413/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-gprmc-from-device-gps) but I'm not a GIS expert. Notice that our location events include details such as velocity etc. that might negate some of the use cases for NMEA frames.